# Vertx custom server/socket for RF communications

Tags: vert.x

My application uses an RF radio to communicate with edge devices and I'm interested in reimplementing it using Vertx. Are there any examples/tips/pointers that might help me get started?

I'm assuming that I'd need to implement a custom server or socket that interacts with the radio to send/receive messages, but I didn't see anything like this in the documentation nor after a quick search. Am I on the right path? What alternative approaches would you recommend?

Help appreciated!

Bree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With vertx core you can create TCP/UDP sockets or high level protocols like HTTP(S)/2 with some extra dependencies you can also create UNIX domain sockets. With your question it is not clear what kind of socket or protocol you're interested in order to help you with an example, pointer to documentation, etc...

Comment: I think what I really want is the Event Bus. I'll bring up my own server and simply publish to the bus. Is this a common pattern with vertx?

Comment: Yes that is a common pattern, please read the docs about it as the eventbus. This could be a basis for a api gateway. Note that the event bus is not persistent, if you send a message and the server crashes the response will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.